# How can I ovecome this error in npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, node-canvas

I'm a beginner programmer, and I'm making a discord bot using node and discord.js. I need a library named `canvas`, but it doesn't install!

I programmed and tested this app on my windows pc, then sent it over to my raspberry server. It didn't work, so I tried deleting and installing the library again, but when installing, it gives this error:

(I'm trying to install it with this command: `npm install canvas`)

````
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@15.0.1 | linux | arm
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v88-linux-glibc-arm.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v88-linux-glibc-arm.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v88-linux-glibc-arm.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for canvas@2.6.1 and node@15.0.1 (node-v88 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v88-linux-glibc-arm.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.0.1 | linux | arm
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.0.1 | linux | arm
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/15.0.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/15.0.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/15.0.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pixman-1' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:327:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:277:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.51-v7l+
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v88"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:327:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1048:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.51-v7l+
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/pi/node/test/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node/test/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.0.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2020-10-27T20_10_02_765Z-debug.log```
````

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First Try installing the binaries for canvas mentioned in https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev
```

Then install canvas:

```
npm install canvas
```

Comment: What to do for mac?

Comment: What to do in windows?

Comment: My organizations Ubuntu VM broke because of this canvas error. If it wasn't for this answer, it would've been snafued. royally. thnx much for ur answer.

Answer (score 20):

Did you start by running `npm init`? I would assume so because of the node_modules folder mentioned in the error, but just checking.

You can install it with homebrew using:

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```

according to the docs here: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

Comment: They aren't using MacOS

Comment: They aren't using Windows either

Comment: You said Windows, not Linux! (And after following links and scrolling a bit, it's clear that brew does not properly support ARM processors)

Comment: Yes: "best-effort basis". i.e. not properly supported.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, It didn't solve my problem, but today I started a new project from scratch, did npm init, and installed all the libraries. It worked! It was probably some stuck in incompatibility from transitioning from Windows to Linux!

Comment: Yo i found merlin here. Worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Works for me on Macbook M1 Pro ->
`arch -arm64 brew install pkg-config cairo pango jpeg giflib librsvg`

Comment: As someone already pointed out, the author of the question is not using macOS. Otherwise, on M1 Pro, one has indeed to recompile all native Node.js addons as almost no one is shipping pre-built binaries - mainly because Github Actions does not support it yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, what resolved the issue was using Node.js v14

```
nvm use 14
```

Answer (score 1):

For those homebrew did not work:

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```

I found out the cause, it was homebrew that was not configuring pkg-config properly after installing it. I am using Mac OSX with M1 Chip.

You have to install Mac Ports and then run

```
sudo port install pkgconfig pango
```

This is a long process so **could take 1 hour or greater** but it solves
the `npm ERR! No package 'pixman-1' found` problem.

the and is taken from [this github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1065)