# why do i keep getting error when i require canvas while making a discord bot with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am learning javascript and working on a discord bot, it was working just fine but, when I tried to add the 'welcome image' I started having errors trying to run it:

```
Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/yessirski/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

and this is the source code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const mySecret = process.env['token']

const generateImage = require("./generateImage")

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES",
        "GUILD_MEMBERS"
    ]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "hi"){
        message.reply("Hello!")
    }
})

const welcomeChannelId = "951832232857862166"

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
    const img = await generateImage(member)
    member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelId).send({
        content: `<@${member.id}> Welcome to the server!`,
        files: [img]
    })
})

client.login(mySecret)
```

generateImage.js:

```
const Canvas = require("canvas")

const Discord = require("discord.js")
const background = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1f/eb/00/1feb002749ce5d44d9f94f1b9f177754.jpg"

const dim = {
    height: 728,
    width: 556,
    margin: 50
}

const av = {
    size: 256,
    x: 480,
    y: 170
}

const generateImage = async (member) => {
    let username = member.user.username
    let discrim = member.user.discriminator
    let avatarURL = member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: "png", dynamic: false, size: av.size})

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(dim.width, dim.height)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

    // draw in the background
    const backimg = await Canvas.loadImage(background)
    ctx.drawImage(backimg, 0, 0)

    // draw black tinted box
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"
    ctx.fillRect(dim.margin, dim.margin, dim.width - 2 * dim.margin, dim.height - 2 * dim.margin)

    const avimg = await Canvas.loadImage(avatarURL)
    ctx.save()
    
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(av.x + av.size / 2, av.y + av.size / 2, av.size / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.clip()

    ctx.drawImage(avimg, av.x, av.y)
    ctx.restore()

    // write in text
    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
    ctx.textAlign = "center"

    // draw in Welcome
    ctx.font = "50px Roboto"
    ctx.fillText("Welcome", dim.width/2, dim.margin + 70)

    // draw in the username
    ctx.font = "60px Roboto"
    ctx.fillText(username + discrim, dim.width/2, dim.height - dim.margin - 125)

    // draw in to the server
    ctx.font = "40px Roboto"
    ctx.fillText("to the server", dim.width / 2, dim.height - dim.margin - 50)

    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), "welcome.png")
    return attachment
}

module.exports = generateImage
```

also I've noticed that the error only pops up when I imported canvas. i am using replit.

Comment: Don't use images of code. Add your code to your question as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question ["How can I ovecome this error in npm install?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562563/how-can-i-ovecome-this-error-in-npm-install)?

Comment: Thank you, but no it doesn't when I try to install canvas it gets installed with 0 errors actually.