# Installing canvas giving error on linux (arm 64) server

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, canvas, discord.js

so I've search all answers on stackoverflow and nothing worked for me, I am getting this error while installing `canvas`

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/container/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c /tmp/install657476664.sh
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/home/container/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/container/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@17.9.1 | linux | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v102-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v102-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.3 and node@17.9.1 (node-v102 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v102-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.9.1 | linux | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.9.1 | linux | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.2 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/container/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/container/.cache/node-gyp/17.9.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/container/.cache/node-gyp/17.9.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/container/.cache/node-gyp/17.9.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/container/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-1027-oracle
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/home/container/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/home/container/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v102"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/container/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.9.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/home/container/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/container/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-1027-oracle
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/container/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/container/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.9.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/container/.npm/_logs/2022-07-10T18_11_02_916Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: try deleting node_modules and trying again `npm i canvas@latest`

Comment: @MalikLahlou I tried that

Answer (score 2):

Use **[@napi-rs/canvas](https://npm.im/@napi-rs/canvas)** instead of node-canvas.

It doesn't require build tools, is a new library and provides better performance compared to node-canvas. It uses [skia](https://skia.org) graphics under the hood which is faster than [cairo](https://www.cairographics.org) used by node-canvas. It also provides better fonts api.

The API is basically the same. It should be pretty much easy to migrate to `@napi-rs/canvas`. It also offers native support for more image formats out-of-the-box. The source code of **[@napi-rs/canvas can be found here](https://github.com/Brooooooklyn/canvas)**

```js
const { createCanvas } = require("@napi-rs/canvas");

const canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// do some canvas here

// asynchronously encode canvas into png image
const img = await canvas.encode("png");

// or synchronous api like node-canvas
const img = canvas.toBuffer("image/png");
```

Comment: I did after all use napi-rs but not being able to find out the issue is pain you know, thanks anyways!

Answer (score -1):

the solution is already given in github discussion & stackoverflow

- https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1447
- [How can I ovecome this error in npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562563/how-can-i-ovecome-this-error-in-npm-install)

I had similar case with installing sqlite3 on my M1 Pro Macbook. The solution bears almost no difference to this answer; it'll probably work.

Comment: I checked and opened another issue in github, nothing worked